# Why is UITextView's text not being replaced?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a short bit of code that is meant to take a string, find words in a library, and replace them from a random array of other words. For some reason, when I hit the button, nothing happens! I made it work in the playground, so what am I doing wrong?

App code:

```
import UIKit

extension Array {
    func randomItem() -> T {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
        return self[index]
    }
}

extension String {
    func replace(target: String, withString: String) -> String
    {
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(target, withString: withString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        maintext.text = "The Dog Chases the Ball"
        self.submit.setTitle("Change It", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet var maintext: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet var submit: UIButton!
    @IBAction func submitTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        self.submit.setTitle("Again", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        var AllWords = maintext.text

        var WordsArray = AllWords.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        var Dog = ["Pup", "Canine", "Wolf"]
        var Ball = ["Frisbee", "Stick", "Car"]


        AllWords.replace("Dog", withString: Dog.randomItem()).replace("Ball", withString: Ball.randomItem())
    }

}
```

Play Ground:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension Array {
    func randomItem() -> T {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
        return self[index]
    }
}

extension String
{
    func replace(target: String, withString: String) -> String
    {
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(target, withString: withString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    }
}

var Text = "The Dog Loves to Chase the Ball"


    //: Old Text Loaded as an array
    var AllWords = Text.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    //: New Word Library
    let Dog = ["Pup", "Canine", "Wolf"]
    let Ball = ["Frisbee", "Stick", "Car"]


for element in AllWords {
    Text.replace(element, withString: Dog.randomItem())
    Text.replace(element, withString: Ball.randomItem())

}

Text.replace("Dog", withString: Dog.randomItem()).replace("Ball", withString: Ball.randomItem())
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're copying `maintext.text` into `AllWords` and then replacing the text in `AllWords`.  `AllText` now has a copy of what's in `maintext.text`, but is not pointing to the textview's `text` property.  After replacing the text in `AllWords`, you should assign `AllWords` to `maintext.text`:

```
var AllWords = maintext.text

var WordsArray = AllWords.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
var Dog = ["Pup", "Canine", "Wolf"]
var Ball = ["Frisbee", "Stick", "Car"]


AllWords.replace("Dog", withString: Dog.randomItem()).replace("Ball", withString: Ball.randomItem())

maintext.text = AllWords // You need set the textview's text here
```

If that still fails, try jumping back on the main thread when setting the text:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    maintext.text = AllWords
})
```

Comment: Thank you!! That helps. Unfortunately I am still not getting any new text when I press the button .

Comment: Print `AllWords`.  Does it contain the value you're expecting?  The only other think I could think of is wrapping the `maintext.text = AllWords` line in a `dispatch_async` block in case you're off the main thread.

Comment: See the update to my answer and try the `dispatch_async` block.

Comment: Hmm... still nothing. I put it right under the line that declares the UIText. Is that correct?

Comment: `print(AllWords)` after you call `replace`.  What is the value?  Is a valid string being returned from `replace`?

Comment: It just says "The Dog Chases the Ball". Weird. It would seem it's not actually replacing.

Answer (score 0):

The type `String` in Swift is a value type that means that any change creates a new instance of `String`.

The string of the text view is left unchanged.

So after the replace task you have to reassign the value to the text view

```
maintext.text = AllWords
```

PS: please name variables with a first lowercase letter